# Use jQuery for responsive image replacement without browser sniff

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I've been researching responsive image replacement techniques and they all have pros/cons. One thing that seems to be common though, is that they all use browser sniffing to selectively set the appropriate image size.

Its currently possible to create a media query statement that can target a "known" given image (let's say the wordpress "featured image") on the page to substitute the lower resolution image at each device-width breakpoint.

For example, if we have this markup for the featured image for given page"

```
<figure class="figureFeatured">
    <img src="myimage-300x300.jpg" />
</figure>
```

And with that markup, if the image name never changes, the media query below will do the job without need of any additional scripting, using pure CSS.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width:480px)
{
    figure.figureFeatured img{content:url(myimage-50x50.png)}";
}
```

The problem, and where I'm hoping jQuery can help, is when you don't know in advance the image name. You need to use the dom to find that and then perhaps use regex to specify the replacement image.

For example, the image in my example is "myimage-300x300.jpg", but it could be any filename with the -WidthxHeight.jpg extension.

Comment: You don't target the image, you target the container.

Comment: The image is being targeted via the css media query

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do the following?:

**HTML**

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image {
     background: url("image1") no-repeat scroll 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width:480px)
{
.image {
     background: url("image2") no-repeat scroll 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
}
}
```

Comment: Sure, but what if image1 becomes image3, the problem of the question is how to create a replacement for ANY image, if you don't know the name, just the location within the DOM. You will not know the filename in advance. You have to sniff that with jQuery somehow and pass that to the media query.